# Having trouble understanding a property of modular congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am given that
$$a \equiv 11 \pmod {19}$$
and $$ c \equiv 13a \pmod {19}$$ 
and I am asked to solve for a $c$ that is between $0$ and $18$ inclusive.

From looking at problems online, it seems that the easiest way to do this is as follows:

$$ c \equiv 13(11) \pmod {19}$$
$$ c \equiv 143 \pmod {19}$$
$$ 143 = 19(7) + 10$$
therefore
$$ c = 10$$
because $$ 19 \mid (143-10). $$

So I have two questions: how is it possible to substitute $11$ as $a$, as my book does not prove this nor mention it and I have a very hard time with proving things myself?

And is that last step (solving for $c$) a trial and error approach, as it seems to be that way?

Comment: $a \equiv 11 \pmod {19}$ translates to $a = 19k+11$ for some integer $k$. So you can replace $a$ by $19k + 11$

Comment: @rsadhvika yea with that method was how I was able to solve the problem but it is a longer process than the above method so I wanted to understand why the above method works

Comment: First see that in $\mod 19$, replacing $a$ by $11$ is same as replacing $a$ by $19k+11$. (multiples of 19 don't matter)

Comment: @rsadhvika So because $k$ can be any integer, then $k = 0$ gives that $ a = 11$ 
Which means $ 11 \equiv 11 \pmod {19}$ and that is indeed a true statement

Comment: Note that there is an infinity of $a \in \Bbb Z$ such that $a\equiv 11 \pmod{19}$. Here $a$ *does not* equal $11$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why does your book proceed this way? That's because congruences, like equalities, are compatible with addition and multiplication, i.e.
$$a\equiv a',\quad b\equiv b'\pmod n\implies\begin{cases} a+b\equiv a'+b',\\ab\equiv a'b'\pmod n
\end{cases}$$
As to the explicit value of $c$, it is not at all obtaind  by trial and error, but by a plain old *euclidean division* of $143$ by $19$.

Comment: so if a,b both share the same remainder under $mod n$ then does $\equiv$ mean the same thing as $ =$ when two values share the same remainder under $mod n$? Therefore  $a+b \equiv a'+b'$ because of the mod class?

Comment: Yes, exactly: actually, we add classes rather than numbers.

Comment: alright that makes sense, I'm not really sure what you mean by adding classes though

Comment: Congruences classes mod $n$ are endowed with addition and multiplication which make them a ring ($\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$). Theses relations are the justification for the way these operations are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo arithmetic is *nothing* more or less than doing arrithmetics on remainders.

And if $a$ and  $11$   have the same remainder, then it *must* true that $13a$ will have the same remainder as $13*11$.

And $143$ must have some remainder when divided by $19$.  What is it?

...........

A fundamental aspect of modulo classes is that the relationship, ($a \equiv b \mod n \iff $n|a-b$ \iff a = b + kn$ for some integer $k\iff a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$) is an *equivalence* relationship.

In essence this means if $a\equiv b \mod n$ then $a$ and $b$ are interchangeable in terms of modulo arithmetic.

This can be proven by if $a \equiv \alpha \mod n$ and $b \equiv \beta \mod n$ then $a*b = (\alpha + kn)(\beta + jn) = \alpha*\beta + n(k\beta + j\alpha + jkn)$ and $a + b = (\alpha + \beta) + n(j+k)$.  So $ab \equiv \alpha\beta\mod n$ and $a+b \equiv \alpha + \beta \mod n$.

So if $a \equiv 11 \mod 19$ then and $f(a) \equiv f(11) \mod 19$ so long as $f$ is a combination of addition and multiplication.

So $c \equiv 13a\equiv 13*11 \mod 19$ because $a \equiv 11 \mod 19$.

And as for $13*11 = 143 \equiv 10 \mod 19$ being trial and error... well, yes, and no.  $a\div n = b$ with $r$ remainder means we can find a $b$ and $r$ so that $a = b*n + r$ and $0 \le r < n$.  That's basic division from the third grade.

So $143\div 19 = 7\frac {10}{19}$.  So $143 = 7*19 + 10$.  So $143 \equiv 10 \mod 19$.

.....

Comment: does this mean that $\equiv$ when talking about modulo arithmetic is equivalent to $=$ if the two values we are working with belong to the same mod class? in this case $ \pmod {19}$

Comment: Yes.  If the relationship is $a$~$b$ iff $a \equiv b \mod 19$ then the set $A_{11}=${..,-8, 11, 30, 49, .....} is a set terms that are all ~ to each other.  There are 19 such distinct sets.  These are called the "equivalence" classes.  $A_{10}=${..,-9, 10, 29, 48,...} is another.  $a \equiv 11 \mod 19$ means that $a$ and $11$ both belong to the same set.  The basic premise is "addition and multiplication ("arithmetic") distributes over equivalence residue ("remainders") classes (sets)".

Comment: In other words if $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ then all the $a+b$ will always be in the same $C$ no matter which $a$ and $b$ we pick.  If $3 \in A$ and $5 \in B$ and $3+5 = 8\in C$ then *any* $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ will have $a+b\in C$.  $155 \in A$ and $-71 \in B$ and $155-71\in C$. If we label the *SETS* A =[3]=[22] and B=[5]=[24] etc $3\in [3]$ and $5\in [5]=$ and $3+5 = 8 \in [8]$  then as $155\in [3]$ and $-71\in[5]$ therefore $155 - 71 \in [8]$.

Answer (score 0):

$a\equiv 11\pmod{19}$ means that $19\, |\, (a-11)$. 
Note that it implies $19\, |\, (a-11)13\, =13a-11\cdot13$, which translates back to $13a\equiv 11\cdot13$.

In addition, $11\cdot13= 147$ gives *remainder* $10$ when dividing by $19$, so we will have $c= 13a\equiv147\equiv10\pmod{19}$.

Also note that sometimes calculating by *negative values* can yield shorter calculations. In your case $11\equiv -8$ and $13\equiv -6$, so they can be exchanged $\pmod{19}$, use the above argument (if not convinced yet), and they of course give the same result: $(-8)\cdot(-6)=48=2\cdot19+10\equiv 10\pmod{19}$.